# Dates Change Upon Sorting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to generate a panel dataset of alcohol consumption over time. The way we do this in Python is like:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.beerinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/2021-September-The-Brewers-Almanac-Beer-Institute-2021.xlsx'


df=pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name='Beer Shipments by State', skiprows= lambda x: x<2 or x >54)

df = df. tail(-1)

del df[df.columns[1]]


df.drop(columns=df.columns[1:29], axis=1,  inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'State'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='State')

df.rename(columns={'value': 'shipments'}, inplace=True)

df
```

Which returns the dataframe

```
               State variable      shipments
0            Alabama   1994.1         234030
1             Alaska   1994.1          26799
2            Arizona   1994.1         295000
3           Arkansas   1994.1         127200
4         California   1994.1        1640146
...              ...      ...            ...
16825       Virginia   2021.6         439000
16826     Washington   2021.6         473000
16827  West Virginia   2021.6  119300.985455
16828      Wisconsin   2021.6      469606.08
16829        Wyoming   2021.6          47000

[16830 rows x 3 columns]
```

But when I sort the date variable like this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.beerinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/2021-September-The-Brewers-Almanac-Beer-Institute-2021.xlsx'


df=pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name='Beer Shipments by State', skiprows= lambda x: x<2 or x >54)

df = df. tail(-1)

del df[df.columns[1]]


df.drop(columns=df.columns[1:29], axis=1,  inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'State'}, inplace=True)

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='State')

df.rename(columns={'variable': 'date', 'value': 'shipments'}, inplace=True)

df.sort_values(by=['State', 'date'])
```

We get

```
         State    date shipments
561    Alabama    1995    212299
1173   Alabama    1996    224432
1785   Alabama    1997    207508
2397   Alabama    1998    232107
3009   Alabama    1999    239510
...        ...     ...       ...
16625  Wyoming  2021.2     30000
16676  Wyoming  2021.3     33000
16727  Wyoming  2021.4     37000
16778  Wyoming  2021.5     48000
16829  Wyoming  2021.6     47000

[16830 rows x 3 columns]
```

Why do the values for Alabama round up to 1995, but for Wyoming, for example, they remain the same (2021.6, for June 2021)? I want for the final dataset to have the state name, the year/month variable (1994.1 ... 2021.6), and have the estimates as they are. What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's because of the way you process the spreadsheet. When two columns names are duplicated (*in your case there is a month of each year, which you ignored*), pandas add a suffix (an incremented number) :

```
print(df["date"].unique())

array(['1994.1', '1994.2', '1994.3', '1994.4', '1994.5', '1994.6',
       '1994.7', '1994.8', '1994.9', '1994.10', '1994.11', 1995, '1995.1',
       '1995.2', '1995.3', '1995.4', '1995.5', '1995.6', '1995.7',
       '1995.8', '1995.9', '1995.10', '1995.11', 1996, '1996.1', '1996.2',
       '1996.3', '1996.4', '1996.5', '1996.6', '1996.7', '1996.8',
       '1996.9', '1996.10', '1996.11', 1997, '1997.1', '1997.2', '1997.3',
       ...
```

You can try this instead :

```
df = (pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name="Beer Shipments by State",
                    skiprows= lambda x: x<2 or x>54, header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1])
          .iloc[:, 27:].rename_axis(index=["state", "census region"], columns=[None, None])
          .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name=["year", "month"], value_name="shipments")
          .reset_index().astype({"year": int}).sort_values(by=["state", "year"], ignore_index=True)
     )
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

         state       census region  year month  shipments
0      Alabama  East South Central  1994   Jan  210152.00
1      Alabama  East South Central  1994   Feb  234030.00
2      Alabama  East South Central  1994   Mar  253624.00
...        ...                 ...   ...   ...        ...
16878  Wyoming            Mountain  2021   May   37000.00
16879  Wyoming            Mountain  2021   Jun   48000.00
16880  Wyoming            Mountain  2021   Jul   47000.00

[16881 rows x 5 columns]
```